# Does android resources override depends on minSdk versions?

Tags: android

Does android resources overriding is enabled/disabled depending on `defaultConfig.minSdk` version in `build.gradle`?

I don't know why this happens but, I guess changing `minSdk` version will disable resources overriding.

resource overriding works on `minSdk` *23* but it's not working on `minSdk` *24 or higher*.

**What I expect?**

`EXTERNAL_LIBRARY` has `library_icon` drawable resource, literally **red_circle**.

Overriding on `B (Library)` `library_icon` as **blue_circle**.

So, `library_icon` should drawn as **blue_circle**.

**Project Structures**:

```
A (Application)
B (Library)
```

**Gradle Settings**:

```
// build.gradle for A 
// ...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':B')
}

//////////////////////

// build.gradle for B
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 23 // (ok when 23, 24 or higher does not override resources)
    }
}

dependencies {
    api EXTERNAL_LIBRARY
}
```

My question is, why resource overriding is not working depends on minSdk versions? I never saw anything related this issue (or just I can't find it)

Comment: I believe resource overriding has been around since at least API 4, maybe even earlier. Different qualifiers were added in different APIs though. This explains it quite well: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: Should definitely work with the latest api version. How are you overriding?

Comment: You need to show what "resource overriding" means to you, what you're trying to do, what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @dominicoder Add explanation about what I'm expecting to. it was deleted while editing questions. sorry about it :/

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I was overriding drawable resources on external library, but it's not working 24 or higher minSdk version. I really wan't to know why this happening

Comment: @KenWolf My explanation is not enough to ask question. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: "Overriding on B (Library) library_icon as blue_circle." - I still don't know what you think "overriding" is. _What are you doing to "override" the icon_? Show some example code.

Comment: Can you check if the library contains the same drawable for multiple api levels? Android always picks the most specific resource qualifier if multiple resources with the same name are available.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I put `library_icon` into `drawable` directory, but `library_icon` on external library was in `drawable-v24`, so I tried to put `drawable-v24` directory but it doesn't working.

Comment: @dominicoder assume my project and external library's resource has same identifier, such as `library_icon` above. I expecting my `library_icon` will drawn not external library's `library_icon`. Sorry this is so hard to explain what I really want

Comment: @SlaneR - let's not assume anything. Update your question to show exactly what the library looks like, what your project looks like, and how you're using the resource. Or create and share a small sample project that illustrates the problem. Stop _describing_ the problem. _Show_ the problem.

Comment: @dominicoder I'm so sorry to poor explanation. I'll keep it mind for further questions. Thanks for your review.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Finally I solved this problem, external library's resource was in `drawable-anydpi-v24` directory. So I changed my module `drawable` to `drawable-anydpi-v24` it works. Thanks for your comment. It would be accepted as answer but I can't ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was using external library's resources because find best matching resources. 
([How Android finds the best-matching resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch))

I was put resource into `drawable` directory which has same identifier in external library, but external library's resource was in `drawable-anydpi-v24`, so it happens minSdk 24 or above.

Finally I solved this problem to put drawable resource into `drawable-anydpi-v24`.